# I have written a bit of jquery and am unsure as to why it is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been writing a website for my partner and am trying to create an image carousel using jquery to change the background style property however it hasn't been working so far all I get is the stock image I set in my css as a placeholder, please take a quick look and see where I've gone wrong

I have a bit of php running to count the amount of photos in a folder specifically for this purpose

```
    <?php 
      $dir="images/ticker-images"
      $file_count = count(glob("{$dir}/*.*"))
    ?>
```

then the jquery is this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var x;
      var y = <?php echo $file_count>;
      var dir = <? php echo $dir>;

      while true do {
        x = math.floor(math.random()*y);
        $("image-ticker").css({'background': 'url("' + dir + '/' + x + '.jpg"'});
        sleep(5);
      };
    };
```

if I've made a rookie mistake be kind, otherwise, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should become familiar with the Javascript Console. This can be opened for a webpage by using the F12 key, or right-clicking and selecting `Inspect Element`. The console tab will show you errors and other messages logged on the page. Yes, you have several errors. These include *PHP* errors too.

Comment: What do you mean *it's not working*? What should it do? What is it actually doing? Are there any errors in your browser's JavaScript console? What steps have you tried in debugging? Help us help you :)

Comment: also numerous online ways to validate syntax in your code. Am surprised it even makes it to the browser without proper php closing tags and missing semi-colons

Comment: Strongly suggest you stay away from mixing languages until you have some proficiency with at least one of them

Comment: Ok so I have made all the changes that chiliNUT suggested, yet the problem still persists, I have the main image that I specify in the stylesheet, but no changing images as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) is a PHP method, not a JS method.
2. Your [do loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) is not structured properly. The `while` condition should come after the do block, not before, as in

   ```
   do {
       // code
   } while (condition);
   ```

   But I think you are better off with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) anyway.
3. Your `dir` variable is presumably a string, so you need to delimit it with quotes.
4. Your php block for `dir` should start out `<?php` not `<? php`
5. Your `dir` and `file_count` php blocks in your js code are missing a closing tag.
6. You are missing a closing parenthesis after your `document.ready`
7. Your php code does not end the lines with [semicolons](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)
8. The javascript `Math` object is capitalized.
9. Your `image-ticker` selector is probably an [id selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp), which needs to be prefixed with a hash (`#`)

Try this:

```
<?php 
  $dir="images/ticker-images";
  $file_count = count(glob("{$dir}/*.*"));
?>
```

then the jquery is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x;
  var y = <?php echo $file_count ?>;
  var dir = "<?php echo $dir; ?>";

  var int=setInterval(function () {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);
    $("#image-ticker").css({'background': 'url("' + dir + '/' + x + '.jpg"'});

  },5000);
});
```

Comment: +1 ouch...more error lines than OP had lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Your php is missing closing tags in the jquery section. It requires the `?>` tag to close. 
Your while loop needs to have its condition in parentheses -> `while( run )`.
 Notice I used `run`, you need a condition when using loops, that can be made to be false. Otherwise you have an infinite loop which results in a browser or computer crash.
**EDIT**
Also, javascript uses the `do {} while();` format, where your loop goes in the curly braces,
and your condition goes in the parentheses.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, I was trying to remember back to some earlier coding that I did elsewhere and got Lua instead of javascript in my head.